# get the all value if latitude and longitude is available in XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<results>
    <result>
        <Country_Code>IN</Country_Code>
        <Country_Name>India</Country_Name>
        <Region_Name>Gujarat</Region>
        <City>Rajkot</City> 
        <lat>13.060422</lat>
        <lng>80.24958300000003</lng>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Country_Code>KE</Country_Code>
        <Country_Name>Kenya</Country_Name>
        <Region_Name>Vihiga</Region>
        <City>Kakamega</City> 
        <lat>0.1182473</lat>
        <lng>34.7334515999997</lng>
    </result>
</results>
```

I want to input `latitude` and `longitude` in textbox and then its match in my xml file it returns there all detail like:-

```
country_code country_name region_name city lat and lng
```

with there value

Answer (score 0):

try this firend.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>
<script>
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
/* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
/* change the title to "XML Title" */
$title.text( "XML Title" );
/* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i am try to first check element value in xml if element value match then return there same level element value... :)